# dynamic 2 dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, list, vector

I have a program that that creates a list of values.  (String, double, double, double )       I would like to store these values in an array, vector, or array that is array[x][4].  How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `ArrayList` of arrays of `Object`s:

e.g.

```
List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

list.add(new Object[]{"string", 2d, 1d, 0d});
```

**Update**:

They can be printed as follows (since we know that the array elements are `String` and `Double`s:

```
for(Object[] row : list) {
    System.out.println(row[0] + " " + row[1] + " " + row[2] + " " + row[3]);
}
```

But I do believe that it's a lot better to use a class here for OOP.

Comment: how would you print the results of something like this?

Answer (score 1):

To keep it simple:

Create Data Object class with 4 fields:

```
class MyDataObject {
   String firstParameter;
   double secondParameter;
   double thirdParameter;
   double fourthParameter;
}
```

Then store this object in List:

```
List<MyDataObject> = new ArrayList<MyDataObject>();
```

if your class is present in the same java file (so it is in the same package) - you can avoid using accessors because of default package visibility access.

Comment: +1: Java is very good at classes, no need to use an Object array just because you would use an array in a different language.

Answer (score 0):

What if you create a class and declare those four fields within it and store the objects of that class into an [`ArrayList`](http://www.lvp.com/data/java%20supplements/The%20ArrayList%20Class.pdf) as shown in the following example.

```
final class DemoClass
{
    String str="";
    double a;
    double b;
    double c;

    public DemoClass(String str, double a, double b, double c)
    {
        this.str=str;
        this.a=a;
        this.b=b;
        this.c=c;
    }

    public void doSomething()
    {
        //...
    }
}

final public class Main
{
    public static void main(String...args)
    {
        DemoClass dc=new DemoClass("SomeStrValue", 1, 2, 3);
        List<DemoClass>list=new ArrayList<DemoClass>();
        list.add(dc);
    }
}
```

Would make it easier I think.